# How to plot a graph in the form f(y) + f(x) = c

Tags: javascript, p5.js, graphing

This applies to P5JS, but I am interested in a general solution as well. I currently have a graphing program where one can enter an equation in the form `y = f(x)`. This could be `y = x^2`, `y = sin(x+5)`, `y = x^3 + 5*(x^2) + 6`, etc.

It works by just running a for-loop from -30 to 30 and giving this value to `x`, and evaluating the right hand side of the equation to get the valid y-coordinate, then drawing a point there. (It then draws a line between the points).

This works fine, however does not allow for equations where a given x value can have multiple y-values, and vice-versa, for example any equation for an ellipse. (`y^2 + x^2 = 5` for a basic circle)

How do graphing softwares go about drawing these shapes, and is there a given peice of pseudocode that would work for plotting the points of a shape like this?

Comment: Which "graphing softwares" are you referring to?  Graphing calculators (like the TI-84) generally cannot accept that equation as is.  You would either have to break it in to 2 pieces having the positive and negative square roots as separate equations and graphing them independently or you could convert it to polar form and then graph it with r = 5.

Comment: @nurdyguy I am refering to sites such as https://www.desmos.com/calculator or http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: In the case of desmos you pick the category of equation which simplifies things.  (If you know it is in ellipse then you can use specific properties to simplify the problem.) In the case of wolframalpha you can input general 2-variable equations which is much much much more complex.  As a "poor man's solution" I'd do a double loop.  Loop through your x-values, plug each value in and then loop through all possible y-values for that x.  You'll end up with a set of (x, y) points.  Connecting the dots is where it gets hairy.

Comment: In Desmos I am able to enter `(y-3)^2 + (x-3)^2 = 5` in the general equation section and get the relevant graph, but I appreciate the advice, I would just need a way to work out where each one fell in relation to others to draw the line.

Comment: If you pick a small enough delta between the numbers then you won't need to "connect the dots" as they will for a picture on their own.  The downfall is it takes quite a bit more processing power.  Note that this is a "brute force" methodology and I'm sure places like wolfram have algorithms which are much more efficient.  Play with it and see what you get.  Sometimes as you work through a problem you start to see cool shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a surprisingly easy problem if you're not concerned with purity.
Really what you're doing is trying to find points where the equation is true.
So in the most basic of senses you could go through all 1000by1000 (assuming a resolution here) combinations of x and y. Then you would compute each side of the equation and see if it fits within a fairly tight tolerance (about a pixel, which depends on your 'zoom').

This is easier on the computer than it sounds. You can make this more efficient by using gradient decent, but that's probably not needed in 99% of equations cause computers are so damn powerful doing the equation a million times doesn't hurt them.

Comment: That makes sense, I guess it's just not ideal that it grows like n^2 for the resolution, especially since I want to apply it to 3D graphing where it would grow like n^3. Could you possibly give some more details of how to make it more efficient with gradient descent?

Comment: I've implemented your solution and with some careful constraints it's working, so thank you very much. It definitely runs slower in this "mode" than how I normally calculate it so any advice on how to reduce computation would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok so if the equation is continuous then it's not too hard. You just find a point on the graph and follow it along the entire graph. If it's discontinuous then there's no clear cut way to go about it. I'd suggest finding points by cutting slices through the desired graph space and then using said found points to find the rest in the graph. This means the smallest thing you'll miss is the size of whatever you diced the graph into.

Comment: I should say the way you find more points from a single one is to make small steps in each direction and fill in the ones that match, and then check the points next to those points and so on. If you want to make this more efficient look up linear flood fill :).